# QGIS: What is the purpose of the Browser "Fast Scan this Directory" option?

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

At 3.10.5, I notice that there is a Browser checkbox for *Fast Scan this Directory*.  However, when I check it, nothing seems to change in the way the Browser operates:

[image]

The [3.10 documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html) does not state its purpose, nor did an internet search turn up anything.

So, what is the function of the *Fast Scan* option?

Comment: I took it to be a "refresh" of a particular directory instead of all of them.  I  often mix QGIS and ArcGIS in my work and have to refresh their browsers to see changes the other made.

Comment: @johns Your idea sounded reasonable, so I tested it.  I checked on the Fast Scan button.  Then I loaded a shapefile into the Layers panel.  I then did an "Export > Save features as >" to a new shapefile.  Unfortunately the new shapefile did not appear in the Browser.  If I restarted QGIS, the new shapefile would then appear in the Browser.  So, I'm still puzzled about Fast Scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a note in the [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/master/ChangeLog) (2012-11-29):

> browser: add Fast Scan option for directories,
>   when activated its items will only be checked for extension, not content

Comment: ... and there are some reference to it when loading data via OGR or GDAL. To be honest, I couldn't witness any impact either